# JScript - How to know if the script was activated using WSH or internally by another script?

Tags: javascript, jscript, wsh, activexobject

So I have a simple JScript file, AKA `MyScript.py`, that may be activated using two ways:

#### Using WSH (Windows Script Host)

essentially double click the file.

#### Internally by other script

AKA `main.js`

```
var strScript = ""; // read MyScript.js file to string
F = new Function(strScript)
(F)();
```

### Question

Is there a way to know, in `MyScript.py`, how it was activated?

### Note

I'm looking for some solution similar to what's implemented in `Python`

`if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as portable as the Python method, but you could check the [WScript.ScriptName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3faf1xkh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property. When MyScript.js is launched directly, `ScriptName` will return "MyScript.js". When it is included from main.js, the property will return "main.js".